# Grunt task for downloading file with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, build, gruntjs

I need a grunt task for downloading a file that is hosted on https. The request will have some parameters, something like:

`https://server.com/services/download?what=someFile&version=1`

I have tried to use [grunt-downloadfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-downloadfile) but all I get is `ECONNREFUSED`. I know that the URL I use is correct, as I can simply paste it in a browser and it works.

How would you solve this problem? I consider writing [grunt-execute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-execute) node script myself, but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Can I see the code you tried?

Comment: I don't want to see the API code I 'd like to see the grunt file relative code. Do you register the download task to be executed with grunt command?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the task execution. If I put http it works (on a random site) if I put https it does not.

Comment: Also I originally linked wrong library, fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example working code with [grunt-http-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-http-download) library, as you can see there is an `https` and it works fine:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        download: {
            foo: {
                src: ['https://nodejs.org/static/images/logos/nodejs-green.png'],
                dest: '/tmp/'
            },
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-http-download');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['download']);
};
```

Output:

> Running "download:foo" (download) task
>   Downloading https://nodejs.org/static/images/logos/nodejs-green.png to /tmp/nodejs-green.png ...
>
> Finished downloading https://nodejs.org/static/images/logos/nodejs-green.png.
>
> Done, without errors.

It works with [grunt-downloadfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-downloadfile) library too:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        downloadfile: {
            files: [{
                url: 'https://nodejs.org/static/images/logos/nodejs-green.png',
                dest: '/tmp',
                name: 'test.png'
            }]
        },
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-downloadfile');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['downloadfile']);
};
```

Comment: Seems, like the library that can do it. I will try it shortly and let you know!

Comment: It actually worked perfectly (the first example). Second did not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of grunt-downloadfile and feel a bit ashamed that I didn't managed to keep the library up-to-date and fix the issues. BUT today I've released version 2. Which does support HTTPS.

Please check the documentation here: https://github.com/mCzolko/grunt-downloadfile